# How to get model addAttribute in jsp page in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have used bellow spring boot controller code to get model addAttribute value in jsp page. Here is my controller code..

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/welcome", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login2( RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, Model model){  
    model.addAttribute("outMessage", "Invaid User ID");
    model.addAttribute("outCode", "1");
    System.out.println("*****Test");    
    return "redirect:/login";
  }
```

Here is my jsp code to display message. but message can not show

```
                <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${outCode == '0'}">
                            <span class="text-success">${outMessage} </span>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:otherwise>
                            <span class="text-danger">${outMessage} </span>
                        </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>
```

How to get addAttribute value in jsp page. Please help me

Answer (score -1):

For redirect , you have to add the values to the flash attribute such that they can still be survived and accessed after redirect:

```
 model.addFlashAttribute("outMessage", "Invalid User ID");
 model.addFlashAttribute("outCode", "1");
```